# When does this construction have meaning?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, orm

Sometimes for good updating object I can write so:

```
session.merge(object);
```

But sometimes it is not enough And I must write

```
object1 = session.merge(object);
session.update(object1);
```

Can you explain differencies between this ways for me?

Answer (score 0):

From the Hibernate [Session](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html) Javadoc:

- [merge(Object o)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29)

  Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent instance. The given instance does not become associated with the session. This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with `cascade="merge"`.
- [update(Object o)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/Session.html#update%28java.lang.Object%29)

  Update the persistent instance with the identifier of the given detached instance. If there is a persistent instance with the same identifier, an exception is thrown. This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with `cascade="save-update"`.

On the following links you can find additional info about:

- [Hibernate object states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5459339/1003142)
- [Downside of merge() over update()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118257/hibernate-downside-of-merge-over-update)