# Spring (Hibernate) updating issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, email, spring-mvc

I have an issue in Spring (or Hibernate) with checking for data existence in DB till updating. I want to update user’s profile and I can change Name, Password and Email fields. Name and Password hasn’t to be unique but Email has to. I show the form with fields filled by user’s old data, when I enter new data  not changing Email it, of course, shows that it is already exists. If delete this check I’ll have two same emails in base. How can I set same data for certain user?

My method for update with checking email.

```
public void updateUser(User user) throws NotUniqueEmailException {
        if (user == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }
        if (user.getUserId() < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (user.getEmail() == null || user.getEmail().intern().equals("")) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        if (getUserByEmail(user.getEmail()).getEmail() != null) {
            throw new NotUniqueEmailException("The email of user not unique! " + user.getEmail());
        }
        currentSession().update(user);
//        currentSession().saveOrUpdate(user);

}
```

And I’ve one more method for checking for existence.

```
public boolean isEmailExists(User user) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        boolean result = true;
        Query query = session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.email=?");
        query.setString(0, user.getEmail());
        User u = (User) query.uniqueResult();
        if (u == null) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

**Update controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateView(@PathVariable("userId")Integer userId,
                             UserForm userForm,
                             HttpSession session,
                             ModelMap model){
        User user=userService.getUserById(userId);
        userForm.setUser(user);
        model.addAttribute("userForm",userForm);
        return"profileupdate";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit.do/{userId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String updateUserProcess(@ModelAttribute(value = "userForm")
                                    UserForm userForm,
                                    @PathVariable("userId")Integer userId,
                                    BindingResult result,Model model,
                                    HttpSession session,
                                    HttpServletRequest request){
        User user=userService.getUserById(userId);
        session.getAttribute("userForm");
        model.addAttribute("userForm",userForm);
        updateValidator.validate(userForm,result);

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            logger.error("Validation error");
            return"profileupdate";
        }

        return updatingUser(userForm,user,model,request);


    }

    private void fillForm(UserForm userForm,User user){
        userForm.setUserId(user.getUserId());
        userForm.setLogin(user.getLogin());
        userForm.setRegDate(user.getRegDate());
        userForm.setComputers(userService.getAllUsersComputers(user.getLogin()));
        userForm.setRole(roleService.findByName(user.getRole().getRoleName()));
    }


    private String updatingUser(UserForm userForm,User user,Model model,HttpServletRequest request){

        fillForm(userForm,user);
        user=userForm.getUser();
        try{
            userService.updateUser(user);
            logger.info("User updated!");
            request.getSession().setAttribute("user",user);
            return"newprofile";
        }catch(NotUniqueEmailException e){
            logger.error("Can't update user - not unique email!!",e);
            model.addAttribute("errorMsg","Email is already in use!");
            return"profileupdate";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the primary key for User ?

Comment: You can  update the record if user with the email already exists

Comment: @Serge Ballesta  PK is user's id.

Comment: @pratim_b Yes, I can update the record if I delete checking. But if I delete checking any user will be able to set identical email.

Comment: Do you update record or do you insert a new record in that case ?

Comment: Why you need to delete the check to update the record. if exists, update else insert.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT : add elements for Hibernate persistence methods

If you want Hibernate to automagically know that it should do an an update and not an insert, the primary key **has to be set** in `user`. As you say the fields have been modified, I suppose `user` fields come from a form input. You have two ways to keep the id :

- store it in a hidden input field in your form - on submit, spring will populate it
- have it in a path variable, get it in your controller and populate it yourself (`@RequestMapping(/.../{id}) public String method(@PathVariable("id") user_id, ...)`)

But it may not be enough and you could have a `merge` vs `update` vs `saveOrUpdate` problem. This other post from SO could give indications [Hibernate : Downside of merge over update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118257/hibernate-downside-of-merge-over-update)

Comment: I've done controller with updating through id. But it still doesn't help. It is posted in the top.

Answer (score -1):

compare the args user.getId() with u.getId()